# Postgres cannot create foreign key to serial

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I'm trying to create some Postgres tables, one has a foreign key on anothers' index:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE File (FooId TEXT NOT NULL REFERENCES Foo (ID));
```

But it results in `ERROR: foreign key constraint file_fooid_fkey cannot be implemented`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appears the types have to "match" or you'll get that error.

This works (change to `int` to match the size/type of SERIAL KEY which is an INT):

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE File (FooId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Foo (ID));
```

Comment: Of course the types need to match. How could you reference an integer value when you can store things like `'foobar'` in that column

Comment: Yeah this question was more like google juice--that particular error message didn't seem well documented, so asking to add it to the community docu :)